# Arranging photos in a vertical position in CommerceHQ platform

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having some problem with my theme for my e-commerce store. Currently, the product images are aligned in a carousel form. (One large main image, 3-5 thumbnails images below in carousel form)

I'd like to change this to show all photos in same sizes but vertically (top to bottom)

This is my code, how do I change it? I've read stuff online and tried making changes but nothing is happening. Please help.

```
{{ set(this, 'title', product.seo_title) }}
{% set mainStyles = load.get( loadQuery.cms_items("main-styles", {limit: 50}) ) %}
{% set buttonText = mainStyles[0].settings["Add to cart button text"]|default('Add to Cart') %}
{% set buttonColor = mainStyles[0].settings["Add to cart button color"]|default('inherit') %}
{% set maxRelatedProducts = mainStyles[0].settings["Number of rows for related items"]|default(1) * 3 %}
{% set quanSelector = mainStyles[0].settings["Quantity selector on product page"] %}
{% set imageCrop = mainStyles[0].settings["Product thumbnail aspect ratio"]|default('Smart crop') %}
{% if imageCrop == 'Wide' %}
    {% set imageCrop = 'wide' %}
{% elseif imageCrop == 'Tall' %}
    {% set imageCrop = 'tall' %}
{% endif %}

<div class="page product" data-productid="{{ product.id }}">
    <div class="container">


        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <div class="fotorama"
                 data-width="100%"
                 data-arrows="false"
                 data-loop="true"
                 data-autoplay="false"
                 data-thumbwidth="113"
                 data-thumbheight="113"
                 data-thumbborderwidth="4"
                 data-thumbmargin="5">
                {% if product.mainImage %}
                    <a href="{{ product.mainImage.getImageSize("jumbo") }}">
                        <img src="{{ product.mainImage.getImageSize("jumbo") }}">
                    </a>
                {% endif %}
            </div>

            <div class="product-no-image{% if product.mainImage %} hidden{% endif %}">
                <img src="/img/icons/image.svg">
            </div>

            <div class="hidden-xs">
                <hr>

                {% set relatedProducts = campaign.recommendations({ "product_id": product.id, "limit": maxRelatedProducts }) %}
                {% if relatedProducts|length %}
                    <div class="row related items-grid">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">

                            <div class="block-title">
                                <h3>Related products</h3>
                            </div>

                            <div class="items">
                                {% for product in relatedProducts %}
                                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 item {{ imageCrop }}">
                                        <a href="{{ site_path(product.url) }}">
                                            {% if product.mainImage %}
                                                <div class="image"
                                                     style="background-image: url('{{ product.mainImage.getImageSize("medium") }}');"></div>
                                            {% else %}
                                                <div class="image empty"></div>
                                            {% endif %}
                                            <p class="title">{{ product.title }}</p>
                                            <p class="price">
                                                {{ product.defaultPrice | currency }}
                                            </p>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <div class="product-head">
                <h2>{{ product.title }}</h2>

                <p class="price">
                    <span id="price">{{ product.price | currency }}</span>

                    <span class="compare">
                        <span id="compare-price">{{ product.compare_price | currency(NULL, {"force_prefix_symbol": true}) }}</span>
                    </span>
                </p>

                {% if product.variants %}
                    <div class="variants">
                        {% for variant in product.allVariants %}
                            <div class="item">
                                <span class="label-heading">{{ variant.variant }}</span>
                                {% if variant.selectorType == "dropdown" %}
                                    <div class="select2">
                                        <select data-variant="{{ loop.index0 }}"
                                                class="product-{{ variant.variant|preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/')|lower }}-select product-select"
                                                title="">
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                {% else %}
                                    <div class="product-colors product-{{ variant.variant|preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/')|lower }}-round">
                                        {% for option in variant.variantOptions %}
                                            <button type="button"
                                                    data-variant="{{ loop.parent.loop.index0 }}"
                                                    data-option="{{ option.option|preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/')|lower }}"
                                                    class="btn-rounded product-color"
                                                    style="{% if option.thumbnail.image %}background-image: url('{{ option.thumbnail.imageUrl }}');{% else %}background-color: {{ option.thumbnail.color }}{% endif %}"></button>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </div>
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}

                    </div>
                {% endif %}

                {% if quanSelector %}
                    <div id="quantity-selector" class="quantity">
                        <span class="label-heading">Quantity</span>
                        <input type="number">
                        <button class="down"></button>
                        <button class="up"></button>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}

                {{ system.getApp('ProductCustomizer', {'product_id': product.id} ) }}

                <button class="btn" id="buy-it-now"
                        style="background-color: {{ buttonColor }}">{{ buttonText }}</button>

                {{ system.getApp('SecurityBadge', {} ) }}

                {{ system.getApp('QuantityLeft', {'product_id': product.id} ) }}

                {{ system.getApp('Timer', {'product_id': product.id}) }}

            </div>

            {% if product.textareaModels %}
                <div class="panel-group descriptions" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                    {% for textarea in product.textareaModels %}
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="section-heading{{ loop.index }}">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
                                       href="#section{{ loop.index }}"
                                       aria-expanded="{% if loop.index == 1 %}true{% else %}false{% endif %}"
                                       aria-controls="section{{ loop.index }}">
                                        {{ textarea.name|raw }}
                                        <span class="icon__state"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="section{{ loop.index }}"
                                 class="panel-collapse collapse{% if loop.index == 1 %} in{% endif %}" role="tabpanel"
                                 aria-labelledby="section-heading{{ loop.index }}">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="typography">{{ textarea.text | raw }}</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>

        <div class="visible-xs">
            {% set relatedProducts = campaign.recommendations({ "product_id": product.id, "limit": maxRelatedProducts }) %}
            {% if relatedProducts|length %}
                <div class="row related items-grid">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">

                        <div class="block-title">
                            <h3>Related products</h3>
                        </div>

                        <div class="items">
                            {% for product in relatedProducts %}
                                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 item {{ imageCrop }}">
                                    <a href="{{ site_path(product.url) }}">
                                        {% if product.mainImage %}
                                            <div class="image"
                                                 style="background-image: url('{{ product.mainImage.getImageSize("medium") }}');"></div>
                                        {% else %}
                                            <div class="image empty"></div>
                                        {% endif %}
                                        <p class="title">{{ product.title }}</p>
                                        <p class="price">
                                            {{ product.defaultPrice | currency }}
                                        </p>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                {{ system.getApp('Reviews', {'product_id': product.id} ) }}
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```